# Random Selection of two different objects causes objects to reference same value

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to write a function that will randomly suggest an origin and a destination to travel between two cities or between the same city but different zip codes.  I have a class to do this:

```
public class CityInfo
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ZipCodes { get; set; }

    private static readonly IEnumerable<CityInfo> Cities = new []{
        new CityInfo{
            CityName = "New York",
            State = "NY",
            ZipCodes = new[]{"10001", "10002", "10003", "10004", "10005"}
        },
        new CityInfo
        {
            CityName = "Washington",
            State="DC",
            ZipCodes = new []{"20001", "20002", "20003", "20004","20005"}
        }
    };

    private static T GetRandom<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Random generator)
    {
        return list.ToArray()[generator.Next(list.Count() - 1)];
    }

    public static CityInfo GetCity(Random random)
    {
        var city = GetRandom(Cities, random);
        city.Zip = GetRandom(city.ZipCodes, random);
        return city;
    }

}
```

The problem I am having is when I go to select two cities with the Get City method both the cities come out to the same value.  I'm calling them as follows:

```
var random = new Random();
var originCity = CityInfo.GetCity(random);
var destinationCity = CityInfo.GetCity(random);
```

When i set a break point before calling the desination city get city function the value of origin city is different than when the function call completes so I am fairly convinced the originCity variable is referencing destinationCity somewhere I am just not sure why or how to fix it

Comment: you reinitlize your random number generator each time - this will give the same 'random' number

Comment: that's not actually what is happening, the value is different in each city, but when destination city is set the value of origin city changes is the problem, but just to be sure i edited my code and it has exactly the same behavior

Comment: If any one else is having this issue the problem was actually caused by  the city variable in the DetCity being passed as a reference from the Cities IEnumerable.  If the same city was chosen then the reference was passed back and changing the zip in one item such as destination city will also change it in origin city because both object reference the same array element causing them to both be the same if the same city is chosen

Comment: As you updated your question not to be the same issue as the duplicate I have reopened your question. Please post your solution you found as an answer so other people can benefit from what you found.

Comment: `Next` on the randomizer expects an exclusive max, not an inclusive one. So instead of `generator.Next(list.Count() - 1)`, it just should be `generator.Next(list.Count())`. For example, `generator.Next(3)` will give you 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: To add on to what Joe said, that is the entire reason it is a exclusive max, so you can do `.Count` or `.Length` and not need to subtract one to use it as a indexer in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin city is the same as the destination about half the time in your example, because there are only two `CityInfo` objects in the list of `Cities`. When the same city is chosen for both origin and destination the object is the same and therefore the `Zip` property selected by `GetRandom(city.Zipcodes, random)` is set again by the destination calling set on `Zip` a second time.

If you want to allow both origin and destination city to be the same `CityName` but with different `Zip` you will need to create a copy of the object (at least for the origin). Note you may still end up with origin equal to destination, randomly.

If you can require origin and destination to be different `CityNames`, then the following code will select random origin and destination `CityInfo` objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace stackOverflowRandomRefTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var originCity = CityInfo.GetCity(random, null);
                var destinationCity = CityInfo.GetCity(random, originCity);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("orig: {0} {1}",originCity.CityName, originCity.Zip));
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("dest: {0} {1}",destinationCity.CityName, destinationCity.Zip));
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public class CityInfo
    {
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> ZipCodes { get; set; }

        private static readonly IEnumerable<CityInfo> Cities = new[]{
        new CityInfo{
            CityName = "New York",
            State = "NY",
            ZipCodes = new[]{"10001", "10002", "10003", "10004", "10005"}
        },
        new CityInfo
        {
            CityName = "Washington",
            State="DC",
            ZipCodes = new []{"20001", "20002", "20003", "20004","20005"}
        }
        };

        private static T GetRandom<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Random generator)
        {
            int n = generator.Next(list.Count());
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            return list.ToArray()[n];
        }

        public static CityInfo GetCity(Random random, CityInfo notThisCity)
        {
            var city = GetRandom(Cities, random);
            while (city == notThisCity)
            {  // if there is only one city this is infinite...
                city = GetRandom(Cities, random);
            }
            city.Zip = GetRandom(city.ZipCodes, random);
            return city;
        }

    }
}
```